# I'm looking for code to connect PyFlink to Pulsar

Tags: apache-flink, apache-pulsar, pyflink

I've been trying various examples, but I need to see how to connect PyFlink to Pulsar. I have Pulsar 2.8.0, Flink 1.13.1 and Scala 2.11. I just need to see how to set the parameters for PyFlink to connect to a topic on Pulsar.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Pulsar source connector is supported in PyFlink since Flink 1.15.0. You can refer to [FLINK-25530](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-25530) for more details.

On how to use Pulsar source connector, you could refer to the examples shown in [PulsarSource](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/api/python/pyflink.datastream.html#pyflink.datastream.connectors.PulsarSource) for more details.